# Timer event isn't working

Tags: c++, allegro

I've been using allegro for some time, and the timer event worked in all my previous projects, but I don't know what happened this time, I want to move a piece as long as the game is going, but it isn't moving at all, so the timer event isn't working, why is that? I've made sure all event sources are registered. Here is the code that reproduces the problem:-

```
int firstStuffXPos = 100;
int firstStuffYPos = 100;
ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *eventqueue;
ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display;
ALLEGRO_TIMER *timer;
int width = 800;
int height = 600;
int FPS = 60;
 bool donePlaying = false;

class MyClass{
public:
int getXPos()
{
    return x;
}
int getYPos()
{
    return y;
}
int x;
int y;
 MyClass(int x, int y){
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    stuffone;
}
ALLEGRO_BITMAP *stuffone;
};
MyClass stuff1[] = {
{ firstStuffXPos, firstStuffYPos},
};
void initialize(){
    al_init();
    if (!al_init()){
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize allegro5." << std::endl;
    }
    al_init_image_addon();
    if (!al_init_image_addon()){
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize image." << std::endl;
    }
    display = al_create_display(width, height);
    if (!display){
        std::cout << "Failed to create display." << std::endl;
    }
    al_install_keyboard();
    if (!al_install_keyboard()){
        std::cout << "Failed to install keyboard." << std::endl;
    }
    al_init_primitives_addon();

    eventqueue = al_create_event_queue();
    timer = al_create_timer(1.0 / FPS);


    al_register_event_source(eventqueue, al_get_display_event_source(display));
    al_register_event_source(eventqueue, al_get_keyboard_event_source());
    al_register_event_source(eventqueue, al_get_timer_event_source(timer));


    }
int main(){
initialize();
for (int nostuff = 0; nostuff < 1; nostuff++){
    stuff1[nostuff].stuffone = al_load_bitmap("blueblock.png");
}
    while (!donePlaying){
        al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0));
        ALLEGRO_EVENT ev;
        al_wait_for_event(eventqueue, &ev);
        al_start_timer(timer);
        if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER){
            firstStuffXPos += 5;
            firstStuffYPos += 5;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
            al_draw_bitmap(stuff1[i].stuffone, stuff1[i].getXPos(), stuff1[i].getYPos(), 0);
        }
        al_flip_display();
    }

    al_flip_display();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it isn't moving at all, so the timer event isn't working, why is that?

What makes you so sure it isn't moving *because* the timer isn't working?
Try inserting a print statement in the `if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER)` block -- I think you'll see that your timer event *is* firing.

It isn't moving because you increment `firstStuffXPos`/`firstStuffYPos`, which never actually get used. Try incrementing `stuffone[0].x`/`stuffone[0].y` instead.

As a side note, there's no need to call `al_start_timer` every time you loop, just call it once before you start your main gaime loop.

Answer (score 1):

So I found your problem and it's bit me in the butt A LOT with other allegro functions.  You are putting an integer into a float variable.  Since you defined FPS as an interger, you must cast it as a float when setting the timer.  By the way, I love allegro, but they don't overload functions and check for wrong containers in a lot of the calls, so it's kind of your responsibility to make sure you know what data type is being sent to each function.  Even if you use a define up too for your FPS, unless you define it as 60.0, it may define as an integer and screw up the timer, causing the program to hang while trying to exit.